# Are preferences persistent across updates

Tags: android

Whilst in the debugging stage and using Eclipse I install myappv1.   Then later I install myappv2 (both have the same package name).   Because the name is different Android installs them side by side.   Will the preferences established by myappv1 be available to myappv2?  I see that if I just install a later version off myappv1 it replaces the original and the prefs seem to persist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, application preferences are persistent across updates. However, you need to understand how Android application signing and versioning works in order to ensure that updates to your application are treated as such.

In short...

When you release an update to your app, you must sign it with the same key as you used on all earlier versions (that way Android knows it's the *same* app). To let Android know that the *version has changed*, increment the value of the `android:versionCode` value in `AndroidManifest.xml` (You should also update the user-displayable `android:versionName` value).

For more details, check out http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html and http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/versioning.html